# Meu código não está comparando corretamente variaveis

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/recebecores/valor.php", function(array) {
        quantidade = array[0];
        document.getElementById('betAmount').value = quantidade;
        var tempo  = document.getElementById("banner").textContent;
        var match  = tempo.match(/[^\d](\d+)/);
        var nr     = match && match[1];
        if(nr    === "4"){
            var red   = document.getElementById("red").textContent;
            var green = document.getElementById("green").textContent;
            var black = document.getElementById("black").textContent;
            console.log(red);
            console.log(black);
            if(red>black){
                $("#enviarpreto").click();
            }else if(black>red){
                $("#enviarvermelho").click();
            }
         }
     });
},1000);
```

Bom, por vezes na parte do if(red > black) e no elseif, ele clica no botão errado, em vez de clicar no certo.

O que poderá ser o erro?

Obrigado.

Comment: Quais são os valores das variáveis `red` e `black`?

Comment: São numeros, que podem variar....

Comment: Se são números, está faltando fazer um [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Você está armazenando os valores em string nas variaveis.

Comment: parse, como assim? Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Converter o valor das variáveis armazenados como `string` em `int` usando [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) ou em `float`usando [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

Answer (score 4):

Você esta comparando `strings`, use `parseInt(variavel)` para converte-la em um `int`, e depois compare as variáveis inteiras, segue exemplo:

```
var red   = parseInt(document.getElementById("red").textContent);
var green = parseInt(document.getElementById("green").textContent);
var black = parseInt(document.getElementById("black").textContent);

//Agora a comparação de "maior que" funcionara corretamente
if(red>black){...
```